# Backbone.js render view once again or re-create?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Currently I am dealing with zombies in my backbone.js application. I have read this exelent article http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ about zombies and extended my project with this:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){
  this.remove();
  this.unbind();
  if (this.onClose){
    this.onClose();
  }
}
```

My question is, how to revert this close process? Can I just call render on the object or do I have to re initiate the object by just overwriting it with a new instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`this.remove()`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L1020) call removes the view's `el` from the DOM:

```
// Remove this view by taking the element out of the DOM, and removing any
// applicable Backbone.Events listeners.
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
},
```

so you'd have to recreate that and rebind all the DOM events. You'll also lose all the Backbone event bindings during the `this.unbind()` and `this.stopListening()` calls. Then there's whatever your `onClose` does (if you have one) so you'd need "undo `onClose`" methods.

Basically, don't try to re-use views, just destroy them (with proper cleanup) and create new ones. Your views should be lightweight enough that killing and rebuilding them shouldn't matter.

Comment: And how do I properly destroy a view? Remove and set to null?

Comment: Derick's `close` is a reasonable approach, then just make sure you don't have any references to the instantiated view hiding anywhere.